Tengo una excepción no deseada al momento de querer actualizar una columna de mi base de datos usando EntityFramework en C#
tengo un problema con una excepción que realmente no lo termino de comprender, lo que quiero es modificar un dato de una tabla de mi base de datos por medio de EntityManager, este es el código que tengo:
    if (cfdsCancel.Count > 0)
{
    await CancelationBL.InitProcess(filesCfd, filesCertificates, swAcces, "");
    bool AnyCancelled = false;
    foreach (var file in filesCfd)
    {
        if(file.Status == (int)CancelEnum.CANCELLED)
        {
            var cfd = await dtx.Cfds.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == file.Id);
            cfd.Stts = file.Status;
            AnyCancelled = true;

            if (cfd.IdCfd == 5)
            {
                var pago = await dtx.Payments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IdCfd == file.Id);
                var pagoRelated = await dtx.RelatedDocumentPayments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IdRelatedDocumentPayment == pago.IdPayment);
                cfd.FinalTotal = pagoRelated.PaidAmount;    
            }
        }
    }
    if (AnyCancelled)
        await dtx.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Esta parte si realiza la acción que quiero:
if(file.Status == (int)CancelEnum.CANCELLED)
{
    var cfd = await dtx.Cfds.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == file.Id);
    cfd.Stts = file.Status;
    AnyCancelled = true;

Sin embargo cuando quiero aplicar lo mismo en el siguiente if me bota una excepción cuando entra a la linea de pagoRelated, la excepción es la siguiente:
if (cfd.IdCfd == 5)
{
    var pago = await dtx.Payments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IdCfd == file.Id);
    var pagoRelated = await dtx.RelatedDocumentPayments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IdRelatedDocumentPayment == pago.IdPayment);
    cfd.FinalTotal = pagoRelated.PaidAmount;    
}


Lo que me tiene confundido es que diga 'Invalid Column Name CfdId' cuando en ninguna de mis tablas tengo una columna llamada de esa manera, entonces no sé si hubo algún tipo de error en el mapeo de la base de datos. Todas las tablas que estoy utilizando están relacionadas (por si había duda), aquí un ejemplo del mapeo de la tabla de RelatedDocumentPayments
entity.HasOne(d => d.IdPaymentNavigation)
    .WithMany(p => p.RelatedDocumentPayments)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdPayment)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_RelatedDocumentPayment_Payment");

¿Algún tipo de solución?

De todo el código que hay, a la fecha y hora del presente comentario, no veo algo relacionado al método Process(string), ¿podrías incluirlo por favor?

Claro, todo esto esta dentro de la funcion:
public async Task Process(string client) {     Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CancellationClient));     var method = $"Process:{client}";     CancelationBL.Client = client;     using var dtx = new CFDI33_Context(SettingsAPI.ClientConnection, client);     Configuration configuracion = null;     PacAccess swAcces = null;     Certificates filesCertificates = null;     List<CFDCancellation> filesCfd = null;     List<Cfd> cfdsCancel = null;     try

Publica el código como parte de la pregunta, no en comentarios, que es imposible de leer. Para incluirlo en la pregunta, recuerda que puedes dar clic en [edit]. Si no recuerdas como funciona el sitio, te invito de nuevo a hacer el [tour]. Un saludo.
